# Materialze CSS framework and Toasts not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm experimenting with [Materialize Toasts](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) in my new project. I can't get Toasts to display at all. Firebug debugging indicates that no toast function could be found, but I don't understand why.

I am trying to call the toast like this:

```
%a.btn{:onclick => "toast('I am a toast', 4000)"} Toast!
```

All my other Javascript components are working. I expected Toast to work the same as I'm importing all the Javascript components from the Materialize library. Has anybody encountered a similar issue using this CSS framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else has some trouble getting toasts to work. It needs to be initialized like follows (As per updated documentation):

```
"Materialize.toast('Hallo World', 4000)"
```

and not like the example given in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the last Version of the materializeCss JS file (my version js file is 0.96) on github https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize

Comment: I already have the latest version. I managed to find a "hack" in the meantime. I replaced the toast.js code in version 0.96 with an older version of the code. Firebug indicated that the toast function does not exist in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to initialize your toast, if this one is generated dynammically by using :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
});
```

More informations about toasts right here :
http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html

Comment: I already have the latest version. I managed to find a "hack" in the meantime. I replaced the toast.js code in version 0.96 with an older version of the code. Firebug indicated that the toast function does not exist in the new version.